# Is there a finite number of $(a, b)$ pairs that satisfy, ${a+b} \leq \frac {{a^2}b+{b^2}a}{a^2 +b^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality

${a+b} \leq \frac {{a^2}b+{b^2}a}{a^2 +b^2}$

1. Suppose that $a,b$ are two positive integers that satisfy the above
   equation. How can we show that there is a finite/infinite number of
   pairs for $(a,b)$?
2. Can there be two positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac
       {{a^2}b+{b^2}a}{a^2 +b^2} =2013$ ; and how can we show that?

Comment: @Lovsovs I think you have reversed the inequality while editing it.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I noticed that, but it was already the way I ended up doing it in the title, so I went with one of them. Do you think it was the other way around? (EDIT: Nope, I actually reversed both of them, sorry!)

Comment: Actuallty I reversed it (again), to make it match the original question.

Comment: Why do you keep on flipping the inequality??

Comment: The reversed inequality that @Lovsovs edited is the correct one I needed. And I edited it again as Lovsovs did at the first time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your expression can be written as
$$ \frac {{a^2}b+{b^2}a}{a^2 +b^2}=\frac{ab(b+a)}{b^2+a^2}$$
Now
$$ \frac{ab(b+a)}{(b^2+a^2)} \geq a+b$$
As $a,b$ are positive integers, $a+b \neq 0$
$$\implies a^2+b^2 \leq ab -(1)$$
Applying A.M-G.M on $a^2$ and $b^2$, we get
$$a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab -(2)$$

This implies (1) is never true.

Comment: What is the meaning of "A.M-G.M" ?

Comment: Arithmetic mean $\geq$ geometric mean

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If we multiply both sides with $a^2+b^2$, which is positive, we get:

$$a^3+b^3+ab^2+a^2b=(a+b)(a^2+b^2)\geq ab^2+a^2b$$

---

For the second one, again multiply both sides with $a^2+b^2$ to get

$$a^2b+b^2a=2013a^2+2013b^2$$

We can rewrite this as $a^2(b-2013)+b^2(a-2013)=0$.

Now it shouldn't be to hard to find the solution.

Comment: How we can show that $a^2(b-2013)+b^2(a-2013)=0$  has no solutions?

Comment: There is a solution. Hint: Think about what happens if $b-2013=0$ and $a-2013=0$.

Answer (score 0):

2. substitute $x=ab,$ $y=a+b $ then you obtain equation $$2013 y^2 -xy -4026 x=0 $$ and on this site https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM you can find a solutions of the above equation.